# How get a List of Entries sorted by Value and then by Key from a Map

Tags: java, list, sorting, dictionary, hashmap

My question is how to sort a `Map` contents based on its values and keys and get a `List` of entries as a result?

First, *entries* need to be sorted by **value** in ***descending order***, and then if *values* are colliding, sort them by **key** in ***descending order*** as well.

**Example** of the given `Map` :

```
Map<String,Integer> data = new HashMap();
data.put("a",10);
data.put("b",3);
data.put("c",10);
```

**Expected Order:**

```
["c", 10], ["a",10], ["b",3]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person>{

    private String name;
    private Integer age;

    public Person(String name, Integer age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person person) {
        if(this.age!= person.age){
            return person.age.compareTo(this.age);
        } else {
         return person.name.compareTo(this.name);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }

    public static void main(String argsp[]){
        Map<String,Integer> data = new HashMap();
        data.put("a",10);
        data.put("b",3);
        data.put("c",10);

        List<Person> collect = data.entrySet().stream().map(entry -> new Person(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        Collections.sort(collect);
        collect.stream().forEach(person-> System.out.println(person));

    Collection<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> result  = collect.stream().map(person -> 
            new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Integer>(person.name, person.age)).collect(Collectors.toList());


    }
}
```

results:

```
Person{name='c', age=10}
Person{name='a', age=10}
Person{name='b', age=3}
```

Comment: If you write an answer to your own question, it should really answer the question as posted (and not something vaguely related). Your question asks for a `List<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>`, not a `List<Person>`.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff updated the response to have 
Collection<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> result

Comment: Then I'll retract my downvote. Still the usage of some Person class is unnecessary (so not worth an upvote).

Answer (score 3):

For that you need to define a `Comparator`.

You can utilize for that purpose static methods that were added as an enhancement of **Java 8** to the `Comparator` and `Map.Entry` interfaces.

Both methods [`comparingByValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.Entry.html#comparingByValue()) and [`comparingByKey()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.Entry.html#comparingByKey()) of the `Map.Entry` interface will generate a ***comparator*** for *values* and *keys* respectively. In order to obtain a **descending order** `reversed()` method needs to be applied on them.

Both *comparators* are chained together with the `thenComparing()` method.

```
Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> valDescThenKeyDesc =
       Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed()
           .thenComparing(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByKey().reversed());
```

Note that compiler is ***unable to infer*** the correct types of the arguments of `comparingByValue()` and `comparingByKey()` based ***only*** on the resulting type of the *comparator*.

Therefore, both `comparingByValue()` and `comparingByKey()`need to be provided with the generic type information explicitly `<String, Integer>` (types of *keys* and *values* respectively).

If it seems too tough to comprehend at first, you might split it into separate lines (in this case, type inference works fine):

```
Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> byValDesc =
       Map.Entry.comparingByValue().reversed();

Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> byKeyDesc =
       Map.Entry.comparingByKey().reversed();

Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> valDescThenKeyDesc =
       byValDesc.thenComparing(byKeyDesc);
```

[*for more information on how to build comparators with Java 8 methods, take a look at this tutorial*](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-comparator-comparing)

The next step is to create a ***sorted list of entries***.

For that, you can either create a `List` of entries manually by passing an *entry set* to the constructor and then apply the method `sort()` on it, or by making use of the **Stream API**

In order to implement it with streams, first, we need to obtain a *stream of entries*. Apply `sorting()` operation by passing the given *comparator* and collect the result into a *list* by applying the terminal operation `collect()`.

```
public static List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> getMapEntryList(Map<String,Integer> data,
                                                               Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> comparator) {
    return data.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(comparator)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String,Integer> data = Map.of("a",10, "b",3,"c",10);

    Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> valDescThenKeyDesc =
            Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed()
                    .thenComparing(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByKey().reversed());

    List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> result = getMapEntryList(data, valDescThenKeyDesc);
    
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

**Output**

```
[c=10, a=10, b=3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use stream api and custom `Comparator`.

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

  static Map<String, Integer> createTestMap() {
    Map<String, Integer> data = new HashMap();
    data.put("a", 10);
    data.put("b", 3);
    data.put("c", 10);
    return data;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    var sorted = createTestMap().entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Comparator
            .comparing(Map.Entry<String, Integer>::getValue)
            .thenComparing(Map.Entry<String, Integer>::getKey).reversed())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    for (var kv : sorted) {
      System.out.println(
          String.format("%s\t%s", kv.getKey(), kv.getValue()));
    }
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `comparer()` method. Instead, you can create an instance `Comparator` (*reminder: it's a functional interface*) by using the same code. And you're just printing the entries, OP wants to create a `List` of entries.

Comment: thanks. udpated to return list, and use lambda directly.

Comment: Sorry for down vote, but `* 1000` don't really make sense to me(no one guarantee the [return value of compareTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-), readability) in this case. Better use `Comaparator.thenComparing`

Comment: @samabcde great to learn `Comaparator`, now the code looks much clearner.

Answer (score 0):

Write a `Comparator<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>` that compares map entries according to your rule. Get a list of entries with `new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet())` out of the map. Sort that list with `Collections.sort(list, comparator)`.